Maui Android prevent access to device settings
We are building an app in Maui that will be used on our devices (and is customer facing) the customers should not be able to access the device settings.
The target Framework is Android (Maui)
We've managed to get the app running in fullscreen mode and as a launcher app.
But when you do a simple 'Swipe down' you can still exit the application, access the settings,...
So we need a way to prevent the customers from opening this menu and any other settings.
For maintenance reasons we can't be fully locked out of the device, so we should have the possibility to override this in some way (f.e. by entering a password)
Any help/guidance is appreciated. ;-)

Does this answer your question? Kiosk mode in Android

Most of the devices that require to be locked, have similar functions build in the OS. For example intents you have to send, etc. Read the docs. If you want to lock an arbitrary android device, and you do not want to deal with google, your best choice will be to create device owner application. Do not bother reading those answer in that questions. They are either incomplete, outdated or plain and simple wrong. If you explain to me the situations in details, I can assist you more.
